# V4 Botframework ActionTypes.PostBack shows selected option in chat

Tags: botframework

We are building a bot where **ActionType.Postback** is not working.
There are places in the Bot where it does work however the example attached does not.
The sample was build using Bot framework 4.1.5.
Any help appreciated.

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "help")
                {
                    var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
                    reply.Text = $"Hello {turnContext.Activity.From.Name}! How can i help you today? ";
                    var welcomeCard = new HeroCard
                    {
                        Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                        {
                            new CardAction {Title = "option1", Value = "option1", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack},
                            new CardAction {Title = "option2", Value = "option2", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack},
                            new CardAction {Title = "option3", Value = "option3", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack}
                        }
                    }.ToAttachment();
                    reply.Attachments.Add(welcomeCard);
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
```

[image: Emulator output]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to just be an error in the Bot Framework Emulator and should work fine if you publish your bot to another channel. I've gone ahead and submitted this as a bug to the development team. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1140

Note that the PostBack Action only works in certain channels and will default to ImShow if it is not supported. In the channels where PostBack is not supported, the response text value will be visible to all participants in the conversation.

Comment: +1 The issue also occurs in WebChannel. What I do not understand how such an obvious and annoying bug has not been discovered earlier?!